# What command to use to send code to R console through AppleScript?

Tags: r, applescript, sublimetext

I am trying to fix an issue re the [`SendCode`](https://github.com/randy3k/SendCode/) package for Sublime Text (this [issue](https://github.com/randy3k/SendCode/issues/150)), and it looks like the problem is that the `cmd` command does not work when writing an AppleScript to send code to the `R` console.

This works:

```
tell application "R"
    activate
end tell
```

But when I try to send some text to the console using `cmd`, it returns the following error:

[image]

Could it be a macOS version specific problem? I am running Big Sur in this computer, but the same AppleScript does work in another machine running Ventura. I wanted to ask first in case there is an easier solution that just trying to update macOS.

Comment: `do script "trying"`

Comment: Not working, it says "Expected end of line, etc. but found “script”.".

Comment: The code I offered had `"trying"` as an example but "trying" was a placeholder. In BNF formalism if would be `do script <system-command>`. The point was that `script` was an appropriate AS command in that context and that `cmd` was not. Furthermore, you have not provide a complete description of your setup or apparently read what programs are suppotted. IN the link to `SendCode` we see "Linux: Tmux, Screen, Gnome-Terminal, Pantheon-Terminal, Mate-Terminal, Konsole, RStudio Desktop". Whereas both Mac and Windows have "R GUI" in the corresponding listing. So setup matters.

Comment: Maybe you are using Rstudio on a Mac and should instead be using the Mac GUI? I would have thought that it it didn't make much sense to set up Sublime so it was sending to Rstudio API , and also thought that it should have been sending to the R API in all OS situations, but obviously I didn't write that code.

Comment: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/12521 ; and https://www.reddit.com/r/applescript/comments/11r9ryj/how_to_post_applescript_code_to_rapplescript/

Comment: So maybe just source the R script from Terminal called from Applescript?  https://support.apple.com/lt-lt/guide/terminal/trml1003/mac  ... as a more OS independent strategy?